# Can anyone tell me the Big O time of my sort algorithm?

Tags: sorting, big-o

I'm not very good at memorizing all the different algorithms, so I've implemented one, but I'm not sure how to calculate the Big O time for it, because there is a moving pointer.

It is not very efficient, or at least there are better sorts out there.

It sorts the array in place by moving a pointer back and forth, starting from position 0 and moving to the right, and once back each time it makes a swap, in order to see if the element to the left needs to be changed too.

Here's the code:

```
function countInversions(arr) {
  var count = 0;
  var i=0;

  while(i < arr.length) {
    // look behind
    if (i-1 >= 0 && arr[i-1] > arr[i]) {
      swap(arr, i, i-1);
      count++;
      i--;
      continue;
    }    
    // look ahead
    else if (arr[i] > arr[i+1]) { 
      swap(arr, i, i+1);
      count++;
      continue;
    }

    i++;
  }

  return count;
}

function swap(arr, i1, i2) {
  const temp = arr[i2];
  arr[i2] = arr[i1];
  arr[i1] = temp;
}
```

edit: It looks like a "Bubble Sort."  I'm still not sure what the big-o is.

Comment: Pointer or not, you implemented a Bubble sort, right?  A bubble sort (unless already sorted) is typically O(n^2)

Comment: Yeah this is a bubble sort, you just do 2 iterations at the same time. You still have O(n^2), worst case with largest or smallest element close to the middle.

Comment: Yes you're right!  Thanks guys. @gview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your sort is indeed bubble sort but just you moved the small item to the first instead of moving the big item to the last.

For the sort algorithms the complexity usually is taken for worse and best and average cases. The best case in your implementation (bubble sort) is when the array is already sorted and the complexity will be O(n).
But the worst and average are **O(n^2)**

BTW, I noticed that you have counted the number of swap actions, just wanted to mention that you should consider the number of the loops in term of the big O calculations. However it is totally your platform and requirement dependent and if for example scanning an array costs almost no time but swapping the items costs more time in your platform then counting the swaps makes sense.

I also would like to recommend some improvements to your algorithm:

Before moving the item to the left you can save the current position and once it is settled down, just move back and continue from the place it was before. See the modified code below.

Anyway the time complexity won't change and it is still O(n^2) but it will give you just a little improvement.

```
function countInversions(arr) {
  var count = 0;
  var i=0;
  var old_i=-1;

  while(i < arr.length) {
    count++;
    // look behind
    if (i-1 >= 0 && arr[i-1] > arr[i]) {
      swap(arr, i, i-1);
      if (old_i<0)
        old_i=i;
      i--;
      continue;
    }    
    // look ahead
    else if (arr[i] > arr[i+1]) { 
      swap(arr, i, i+1);
      continue;
    }

    if (old_i>0){
      i=old_i;
      old_i=-1;
    }
    i++;
  }
  return count;
}

function swap(arr, i1, i2) {
  const temp = arr[i2];
  arr[i2] = arr[i1];
  arr[i1] = temp;
}
```